# Converting to datetime

Tags: python, pandas, python-datetime

I am a begginer in Python. I have an issue with converting my data to date time format. In the column DTNAIPRS, I have :

```
0    1972-12-22
1    1936-04-01
2    1925-10-05
3    1926-07-09
4    1952-01-12
5    1964-12-31
6    1940-01-13
7    1942-09-01
8    1939-01-12
9    1954-04-14
10   0001-01-01
11   1944-04-18
12   0001-01-01
13   1932-11-16
14   1936-05-18
15   1936-07-02
16   1944-01-13
17   1954-06-20
18   1927-02-14
19   1938-04-29
20   0001-01-01
```

And when I try to transform it in a date time with this : `test = pd.to_datetime(T_Client.DTNAIPRS.values)`

I have this error :

```
>Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/zeppelin_pyspark-6081451798601516313.py", line 349, in <module>
    raise Exception(traceback.format_exc())
Exception: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/zeppelin_pyspark-6081451798601516313.py", line 342, in <module>
    exec(code)
  File "<stdin>", line 4, in <module>
  File "/misc/anaconda2-4.4.0/envs/dev2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/tools/datetimes.py", line 380, in to_datetime
    result = _convert_listlike(arg, box, format)
  File "/misc/anaconda2-4.4.0/envs/dev2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/tools/datetimes.py", line 306, in _convert_listlike
    raise e
OutOfBoundsDatetime: Out of bounds nanosecond timestamp: 1-01-01 00:00:00
```

Could you help me please ?
Thanks

Comment: Try this: https://chrisalbon.com/python/basics/strings_to_datetime/

Comment: Try specifying a format when parsing `pd.to_datetime(T_Client.DTNAIPRS, format='Y-m-d')`. Note that `pd.to_datetime` can handle `pd.Series`

Comment: Hello every one, thanks for your help. @SergeBallesta an example of my data :

0     1972-12-22
1     1936-04-01
2     1925-10-05
3     1926-07-09
4     1952-01-12
5     1964-12-31
6     1940-01-13
7     1942-09-01
8     1939-01-12
9     1954-04-14
10    0001-01-01
11    1944-04-18
12    0001-01-01
13    1932-11-16
14    1936-05-18
15    1936-07-02
16    1944-01-13
17    1954-06-20
18    1927-02-14
19    1938-04-29
20    0001-01-01

Comment: Ok, but at it is an important information it should be in the question. I have edited it for you to show what I expected. And @ManojKumar guess was correct: the error is caused by the `0001-01-01` values at index 10 and 20.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you column contains (weird) date that cannot be represented in the underlying `pd.Timestamp` type because it is derived from the numpy datetime64 type (see [Manoj Kumar's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55160723/3545273) for details).

A simple way would be to filter out those values before the conversion:

```
pd.to_datetime(T_Client.DTNAIPRS.where(T_Client.DTNAIPRS>='1677-09-22'))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 1):

Since pandas represents timestamps in nanosecond resolution, the time span that can be represented using a 64-bit integer is limited to approximately 584 years

your date value out of range `1-01-01 00:00:00` so it is out of bounds error.

```
In [92]: pd.Timestamp.min
Out[92]: Timestamp('1677-09-21 00:12:43.145225')

In [93]: pd.Timestamp.max
Out[93]: Timestamp('2262-04-11 23:47:16.854775807')
```

[Refer here](http://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/user_guide/timeseries.html#timestamp-limitations), 
[Out of bounds](http://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/user_guide/timeseries.html#timeseries-oob)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a step by step

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

d = ['1972-12-22','1936-04-01','1925-10-05','1926-07-09','1952-01-12']
df = pd.DataFrame({'dates' :d})
df['dates'] = df['dates'].astype(pd.datetime)
df['dates'].dtype
df2 = pd.to_datetime(df['dates'])
print(df2)
```

Here it is tried in a Google Colab, I think this is what you were looking for
[image: Working Output]

If you face any additional Issues, let me know.

Comment: @SergeBallesta In this case yes as in both cases it will remain as an object type, but I have seen sometimes, if in a particular row, there is a slight error, it is easier to identify with this approach., and thus the full blown approach :)

Answer (score 0):

i'm using this code to convert str to time.
first apply the format that you want to have, in my case it's hour/minute/second
you can insert yyyy-mm-dd

then select the column needs to be changed and change the `.dt.time` to `.dt.date`

```
frmt= '%H:%M:%S'
df['column name'] = pd.to_datetime(df['column name'],format=frmt).dt.time
```

good luck